# How to install ROS indigo in Ubuntu 14.04 trusty 64-bit?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when I tried to install ROS in a 64-bit Ubuntu, some problems occurred.

---

```
arkin@arkin-OptiPlex-790:~$ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-desktop-full 

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree     
  
Reading state information... Done

Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

 ros-indigo-desktop-full:i386 : 

Depends: ros-indigo-desktop:i386 but it is not going to be installed

Depends: ros-indigo-perception:i386 but it is not going to be installed

Depends: ros-indigo-simulators:i386 but it is not going to be installed

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

===============================================

What is the problem? How to solve it?

Also I tried in Synaptic. I typed "`ros-indigo-desktop`" in the filter and the results are:

```
ros-indigo-rosh-desktop: i386

ros-indigo-rosh-desktop-plugins: i386

ros-indigo-desktop-full: i386

ros-indigo-desktop: i386
```

why they all have an suffix "i386"? (my OS is Ubuntu-14.04-AMD64)

But if I search it in terminal, it shows that:

```
arkin@arkin-OptiPlex-790:~$ sudo apt-cache search ros-indigo-desktop

[sudo] password for arkin: 

ros-indigo-desktop - A metapackage to aggregate several packages.

ros-indigo-desktop-full - A metapackage to aggregate several packages.
```

Does the ROS have 64bits version and 32bits version respectively?

How to install a 64-bit version of ROS correctly in a AMD64 version of Ubuntu 14.04 trusty?

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190177/how-to-install-ros-indigo-in-ubuntu-14.04-trusty-64-bit?/) by [arkin](https://answers.ros.org/users/20013/arkin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2014-08-14

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on 2014-08-14**:
Tell us please which architecture you have typing in a console:

```
$uname -m
```

**Comment by [arkin](https://answers.ros.org/users/20013/arkin/) on 2014-08-15**:
I don't know how to make the code typed in a console showed in a cell. How to make it? It makes the text very easy to read.

**Comment by [Anurag](https://answers.ros.org/users/28030/anurag/) on 2017-07-11**:
Copy the text after '$' and paste it in a terminal(ctrl+alt+T)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This looks like your package manager tries to install the i386 version of ROS packages even though you are on a amd64 (64bit) system. I´m not exactly sure what the cause is, but it appears there is some misconfiguration in your system/package management setup.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-08-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [arkin](https://answers.ros.org/users/20013/arkin/) on 2014-08-14**:
I just tried to install the ROS indigo following the tips on the ROS website http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu. But how to let the apt-get download a AMD64 version ROS? Is there ROS indigo 64bits and 32bits respectively?

**Comment by [Joao Luis](https://answers.ros.org/users/19882/joao-luis/) on 2014-08-14**:
I think that you should try to setup the mirrors. Try these commands:

```
sudo sh -c '. /etc/lsb-release && echo "deb http://mirror.umd.edu/packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $DISTRIB_CODENAME main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/ros.key -O - | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-desktop-full
```

I think that you'll be able to download and install de desktop-full version

**Comment by [arkin](https://answers.ros.org/users/20013/arkin/) on 2014-08-15**:
Thank you. I tried the commands and replaced the "$DISTRIB_CODENAME" with my ubuntu versin "trusty", but it still does not work.
It shows:

$uname -m

arkin@arkin-OptiPlex-790:~$ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-desktop-full

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done

Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.

The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
ros-indigo-desktop-full:i386 : Depends: ros-indigo-desktop:i386 but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-indigo-perception:i386 but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-indigo-simulators:i386 but it is not going to be installed

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Is there any problems with my package manager setting or system setting?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2014-08-18**:
If synaptic is trying to install i386 you have set a setting somewhere to tell apt to install i386 instead of amd64. You'll need to find that setting and undo it. There are 32 and 64 bit versions of ROS packages.

**Comment by [manipulator](https://answers.ros.org/users/22010/manipulator/) on 2015-07-08**:
Oh,my god, now ,I have met the same problem.
I am looking forward to finding a approach.

**Comment by [Anurag](https://answers.ros.org/users/28030/anurag/) on 2017-07-11**:
Amazing. This worked. Setting up the mirrors worked !! I am new to ubuntu and i just followed the instructions in this post. I would be delighted if someone explains me what just happened

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe gazebo4 was installed, remove it and libraries.

Run the command as follows.

`$ sudo apt-get install libsdformat1`

Then install indigo. good luck!

---

Originally posted by [Guangqi Chen](https://answers.ros.org/users/20438/guangqi-chen/) with karma: 113 on 2014-10-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 10

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [minerva](https://answers.ros.org/users/21509/minerva/) on 2015-01-28**:
Thankss! it worked for me.

**Comment by [blasco23](https://answers.ros.org/users/23917/blasco23/) on 2015-09-16**:
woow man this solution is the best, 1 hour searching, very thanks.

**Comment by [science00000](https://answers.ros.org/users/25431/science00000/) on 2016-01-02**:
I removed Jade and re-install indigo version, the same prob. Thank you.

**Comment by [Kiran](https://answers.ros.org/users/25867/kiran/) on 2016-02-06**:
Awesomee.. worked for me, thanks..

**Comment by [jubeira](https://answers.ros.org/users/29146/jubeira/) on 2017-05-06**:
Thanks! Worked for me.
I think in my case the problem was caused because I had installed/ removed a different distro previously.

**Comment by [Tonystark124](https://answers.ros.org/users/5138/tonystark124/) on 2017-07-16**:
removing gazebo did it for me

**Comment by [mcamarneiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/27884/mcamarneiro/) on 2017-09-26**:
Not for me

**Comment by [wuandwen1](https://answers.ros.org/users/33231/wuandwen1/) on 2018-01-10**:
God!!!!!! It works!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Should update after install libsdformat1. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I ran into the problem. trying to manually installing it resulted in a number of packages needed to be installed. But then it worked:

```
sudo apt-get install tcl-vtk
sudo apt-get install python-vtk
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-pcl-ros
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-perception-pcl
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-perception
```

and now the full install works. when you run the line:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-desktop-full
```

---

Originally posted by [jtim](https://answers.ros.org/users/27497/jtim/) with karma: 153 on 2016-07-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Alymna](https://answers.ros.org/users/22125/alymna/) on 2016-08-05**:
Thanks!, its works in ubuntu 14.04.5!.

**Comment by [mr101470](https://answers.ros.org/users/29234/mr101470/) on 2017-02-21**:
Thanks, It solves my problem as well !